Trying to Install Eclipse IDE for JAVA in SAP. I receive the error below in the Install Log ands cant determine the appropriate fix
Im installing the Eclipse IDE 2024-06 for Java Developers to be used in SAP. The install Log gives me the error below and I cant determine the correct action to take. There area some questions posed close to this but not an exact message on the message content.
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/content.xml.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Jay
I am expecting this to install cleanly after the download and install are executed.

Are you behind a proxy? With which Java do you run Eclipse? With the Java shipped with Eclipse (recommended) or a JDK/JRE installed on your system (not recommended)? Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <).
